# How to put non-project build files on build server during build?

Tags: powershell, tfs

Tools: Team Foundation Server 2012
NuGet: 3.0
Powershell: 3.0

I would like to know how to put build related files onto the build server during the build process.

We have a CI Build that runs on check in, so unless we want the build firing every time we update our nuget.config or a powershell script we need to store them someplace else.

I can put them in a separate team project, and add them to our Working folders, but then again TFS will launch a build whenever we make a change to our build files.  We don't want that.

Is there no way to host some build files into TFS and download them into the build server during build that does NOT cause a new build to fire if you change those files?

If I change a PS1 file, we don't want the build running because of that.

Answer (score 1):

When checking them in you can add: `***NO_CI***` to the comment, and CI builds will not trigger.

Other than that, you can fire off a Powershell script by customizing the XAML and adding an Invoke process task to call powershell.exe and passing the powershell script you do keep in source control.

From there you can either use OneGet or Download-File to fetch and install anything you need.

Comment: Thank you.  I have never heard of One-Get or Download-File.  I did find a tool called TFSExport.exe.  That does what I need.  I am guessing One-Get and Download-File do something similar?

Comment: Oneget is a package manager for Windows that can fetch chcolatey, nuget, powershell gallery and other resources. Download-file is the powershell command to download files from any web location. And tfsexport would indeed work to grab files from source control.